# Open Android app from the browser and wait for result

Tags: android, browser, cordova

Is it possible to open an Android app from a browser and wait for a response? I think that in native apps this is done by `startActivityForResult()`.

I'm open to use PhoneGap or writing a PhoneGap plugin if this make it possible.

Comment: Are you looking for that? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Comment: That's the easy part. The tough part is getting a response from the app you have opened.